# Distribution of one test (Classic Normal Regression)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, least-squares

I am distressed because I have the following problem without solution regarding Classic Normal Regression. Consider test about the CNR parameter $\beta$. We have: $y = X \beta + u $, $u \sim N (0, \sigma^2 I)$, $H$ a $p\times k$ matrix  with rank $p$  and

$$H_0: H\beta = r \quad vs\quad H_1: H\beta \neq r$$

It is known that the OLS estimator $b = (X'X)^{-1}X' y = A y$ is normal distributed, $b \sim N(\beta,\sigma^2 Q^{-1} )$, where $Q = (X'X)$. Taking $b - \beta$, it is clear that:

$E(b - \beta) = 0$ and $V(b - \beta) = \sigma^2 Q^{-1}$, then $(b - \beta) \sim N(0, \sigma^2 Q^{-1})$

Taking $H(b - \beta) = Hb - r$ and considering the null hypothesis $H_0$, we have that

$E(Hb - r) = 0$, and $V(Hb - r)= HQ^{-1}H'$ , then $(Hb - r) \sim N(0, HQ^{-1}H')$.

So, what is the theorem or rule for use to prove the following facts (if they are true)

1. $\frac{(HQ^{-1}H')^{1/2}}{\sigma} (Hb - r) \sim N(0, I_p) $
2. $\frac{(Hb - r)' (H Q H') (Hb - r)}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^{2}(p)$.

I tried to use the following fact (Goldberger book) but it does not match. The fact is: suppose that the n x 1 vector $y \sim N(\mu , \Sigma)$. Let $w = (y - \mu)' \Sigma^{-1}(y - \mu)$. Then, $w \sim \chi(n)$.

In other chapter, Goldberg does $t = Hb$, $\theta= H \beta$, with $b \sim N(\beta,\sigma^2 Q^{-1} )$ and $t \sim N(\theta,\sigma^2 D^{-1} )$, where $D= (HQ^{-1}H')^{-1}$. It is easy verification because
$$E(t) = E(Hb) = H E(b) = H\beta = \theta$$
$$V(t) = H V(b) H' = \sigma^2 HQ^{-1}H' $$

So, he concludes using the mentioned fact that
$$\frac{(t - \theta)' D (t - \theta)}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^{2}(p)$$

But I can not match the same formula. Some help?